# syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND (SyntaxError) from -e:1

Tags: ruby

```
class Movie

class Playlist
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @movies = []
  end

  def add_movie(movie)
    @movies << movie
  end

  def play
    puts "#{@name}'s playlist:"
    puts @movies

    @movies.each do |movie|
      movie.thumbs_up
      puts movie
    end
  end
end

movie1 = Movie.new("Pride")
movie2 = Movie.new("Heaven")
movie3 = Movie.new("While")

playlist1 = Playlist.new("Brenda")
playlist1.add_movie(movie1)
playlist1.add_movie(movie2)
playlist1.add_movie(movie3)
playlist1.play
```

I am new to Ruby and do not understand what is wrong with this code. I am getting the error

```
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND (SyntaxError) from -e:1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

You have started `class Movie` without closing it. Your code should be something like:

```
class Movie
end

class Playlist
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @movies = []
  end

  def add_movie(movie)
    @movies << movie
  end

  def play
    puts "#{@name}'s playlist:"
    puts @movies

    @movies.each do |movie|
      movie.thumbs_up
      puts movie
    end
  end
end

movie1 = Movie.new("Pride")
movie2 = Movie.new("Heaven")
movie3 = Movie.new("While")

playlist1 = Playlist.new("Brenda")
playlist1.add_movie(movie1)
playlist1.add_movie(movie2)
playlist1.add_movie(movie3)
playlist1.play
```

This will also generate some problems though. You are using many `Movie` methods that you have not defined. You should complete your `Movie` class before being able to use it in the `Playlist` class.